# Typescript picking namespace instead of function while import

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, tsconfig

I am working on a project in which i wanted to generate typings from graphql using gql2ts library. In the gql-2-ts file i'm using a namespace import for glob , but typescript is showing me error which is intended. I then changed the import to default import but still it is picking the namespace object instead of function.

**gql-2-ts.ts**

```
import fromQuery from '@gql2ts/from-query'
import DEFAULT_OPTIONS from '@gql2ts/language-typescript'

import * as fs from 'fs-extra'
import * as  G from 'glob'  // namespace import 
// import  G from 'glob'    // default import 
import * as graphql from 'graphql'
import * as path from 'path'
import {promisify} from 'util'

const NO_OF_DIRECTORIES_OFFSET = 2
const {Kind} = graphql
const glob = promisify(G)

const readFile = promisify<string, Buffer>(fs.readFile)
const writeFile = <(file: string, content: string) => void>(
  promisify(fs.writeFile)
)

const removeWhiteSpace = (q: string) =>
  q.replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/\s\s*/g, ' ')

const identity = <T>(arg: T): T => arg

const main = async () => {
  const {data} = await fs.readJSON('graphql.schema.json')
  const args = process.argv.slice(2)
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    const cwd = path.resolve(process.cwd(), args[i])
    const files = await glob('**/*.graphql', {
      cwd: cwd
    })

    const allEnumsArray = await Promise.all(
      files
        .map((i) => path.resolve(cwd, i))
        .map((path) => compileFile(path, data, args[i]))
    )

    const enumsData: EnumData = {}
    allEnumsArray.forEach((enumsMap) => {
      if (enumsMap) {
        Object.keys(enumsMap).forEach((enumName) => {
          enumsData[enumName] = enumsMap[enumName]
        })
      }
    })

    const allEnums = Object.keys(enumsData)
    await Promise.all(
      allEnums.map((enumName) =>
        writeEnumsFile(enumName, enumsData[enumName], args[i])
      )
    )

    console.log(`Compiled ${files.length} files inside ${args[i]}`) // tslint:disable-line
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error(err) // tslint:disable-line
  process.exit(1)
})
```

this is my **tsconfig** file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom", "dom.iterable"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I'm getting the below error in case of namespace import

- Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead. *

and while using the default import

*. from_query_1.default(...).map is not a function*

because it picked the namespace object .

I found one doc related to it , but that didn't helped much.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html

> Note: The new behavior is added under a flag to avoid unwarranted breaks to existing code bases. We highly recommend applying it both to new and existing projects. For existing projects, namespace imports (import * as express from "express"; express();) will need to be converted to default imports (import express from "express"; express();).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. There was version conflict in some of the libraries .
Use these versions for the following libraries

- "@gql2ts/from-query": "^1.9.0",
- "@gql2ts/language-typescript": "^1.9.0"

and use default import, it will work . Keeping the post in case someone bumps into the same error.